# AutoMapper IMemberValueResolver source object to member property mapping issue

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a nested Entity Framework object that contains translations for a display title that is used in a drop down list. I'm trying to resolve the display title from the entire source object, but I can't figure out the correct syntax.

Here is the resolver:

```
public class IssueTypeResolver : IMemberValueResolver<lstIssueType, string, string, string>
{
    public string Resolve(lstIssueType source, string destination, string sourceMember, string destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // culture override from resources if available
        var cultureCode = context.Options.Items["CultureCode"].ToString();
        if (source.refResourceType != null && source.refResourceType.Resources != null)
        {
            var cultureOverride = source.refResourceType.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CultureCode == cultureCode);
            if (cultureOverride != null)
            {
                return cultureOverride.ResourceText;
            }
        }

        return source.DisplayTitle;
    }
}
```

And this is the config map:

```
cfg.CreateMap<DataAccess.DbModel.lstIssueType, Contract.IssueType>()
    .ForMember(
        d => d.Description, 
        opts => opts.ResolveUsing<IssueType2Resolver, string>(????));
```

I need to pass the entire lstIssueType in as the source, but I can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: [Examples](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IMemberValueResolver&type=).

Answer (score 3):

The solution if anyone is interested is below and uses a `IValueResolver` rather than an `IMemberValueResolver`:

```
public class IssueTypeResolver : IValueResolver<lstIssueType, IssueType, string>
{
    public string Resolve(lstIssueType source, IssueType destination, string member, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var cultureCode = context.Options.Items["CultureCode"].ToString();
        if (source.refResourceType != null && source.refResourceType.Resources != null)
        {
            var cultureOverride = source.refResourceType.Resources.FirstOrDefault(r => r.CultureCode == cultureCode);
            if (cultureOverride != null)
            {
                return cultureOverride.ResourceText;
            }
        }

        return source.DisplayTitle;
    }
}
```

And the matching config map:

```
cfg.CreateMap<lstIssueType, IssueType>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Description, opts => opts
        .ResolveUsing<IssueTypeResolver>(src => src.refResourceType));
```